# Autocomplete textbox freezes while executing query. Must be a better way!

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml

everyone! I searched the best I could and did not find exactly the help I was looking for.

### **Problem**

AutoCompleteTextbox FREEZES and "eats" characters while query is performed

### **Asking for**

Mimic Google Instant functionality

### **Background**

First things first: C#, WPF, .NET 4.0

Ok, now that's out of the way, I'm trying to find the best way to implement a dynamic AutoComplete Textbox, which queries a database for results after each letter typed.

The following code gets executed when the AutoCompleteTextBox's TextChanged event is fired:

```
    public void Execute(object sender, object parameter)
    {
        //removed some unnecessary code for the sake of being concise

        var autoCompleteBox = sender as AutoCompleteTextBox;
        var e = parameter as SearchTextEventArgs;

        var result = SearchUnderlyings(e.SearchText);

        autoCompleteBox.ItemsSource = result;
    }
```

Now, let's say that `SearchUnderlyings(e.SearchText)` takes an average of 600-1100ms - during that time, the textbox is frozen and it "eats" any keys pressed. This is an annoying problem I've been having. For some reason, the LINQ in `SearchUnderlyings(e.SearchText)` is running in the GUI thread. I tried delegating this to a background thread, but still same result.

Ideally, I would like the textbox to work the way Google Instant does - but I don't want to be "killing" threads before the server/query can return a result.

Anyone have experience or can offer some guidance which will allow me to query as I type without freezing the GUI or killing the server?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
var result = SearchUnderlyings(e.SearchText);
```

Runs synchronously, locking the UI thread. The way to cure this would be to switch to an asynchronous pattern, where you start the query, and then do something when it finishes.

This article demonstrates it pretty nicely, and shows some solutions - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AsyncMethodInvocation.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had experimented with this at one point, but I was a bit lazy - I did this: Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>result=SearchUnderlyings(e.SearchText)); but where I got lazy was when I had to implement some thread-safety, because several threads were trying to set autoCompleteBox.ItemsSource. But the article is excellent. Thank you. I will edit/update my Question as soon as I come up with my solution (may be a combination of your answer and j0rd4n's).

Comment: You nailed it when you said that the line was locking the UI thread. Thanks a lot. Check out my solution to see how I got around it.

Answer (score 2):

What is probably killing you is setting the binding source over and over again (which is why running the query on a background thread doesn't make a difference).

You might consider the algorithm as a whole.  Depending on your data, you could wait until the user enters the first three characters and then do one large query against the database.  Bind the item source once.  Each character typed afterwards just performs a filter against your data that is already cached on the client.  That way you are not hitting the database over and over (which is going to be terribly expensive).

Or consider just bringing back three or so results from the DB to keep your service serialization time down.

Comment: I'm going to test what you suggested (setting binding source over and over) to see if that really is the case but in the meantime, I really like your suggestion to query once and filter against data already cached. What if I were to query based on the first letter, then every subsequent letter typed just filters against what's cached? Anyway, thanks for the post - got me thinking!

Comment: @Chris - Yep, that would be a good approach too.  The number of initial letters really depends on the total number of records you plan to pull back.  If you are querying back more data than what is performant to bind, you might wait until you have more letters.  You'll have to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

So, we kind of hacked something quick. By making the calls to SearchUnderlyings(e.SearchText) asynchronous, my GUI thread is no longer blocked and the textbox is no longer "eating" key presses. By adding the `lastQueryTag == _lastQuery` check, we are trying to ensure some thread-safety, allowing only the most recent query to set the ItemsSource.

Perhaps not the most ideal or elegant solution. I am still open to further critiques and suggestions. Thank you!

```
private long _lastQuery = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

public void Execute(object sender, object parameter)
{
    var autoCompleteBox = sender as AutoCompleteTextBox;
    var e = parameter as SearchTextEventArgs;

    // removed unecessary code for clarity

    long lastQueryTag = _lastQuery = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {                        
        var result = SearchUnderlyings(e.SearchText);

         System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatch(() =>
         {
             if (lastQueryTag == _lastQuery)
                  autoCompleteBox.ItemsSource = result;
         });
    });
}
```